# Can I use "Récépissé de demande de carte de séjour to re-enter" to France?

Tags: legal, france, paperwork

I am student in France but I am not French. During the holiday, I came back to my country. Before I came back, I have received the "Recepisse De Demande De Carte De Sejour" in the form of paper from Préfecture finistere. My school told me that I can use it to reenter to France. Is it true? I do worry because I searched on the internet and there are some people said I can not use it to reenter to France.

[image: Here is the picture of Récépissé de demande de carte de séjour to re-enter]

Comment: Hi Willy and welcome to Travel SE. Unfortunately your question is about immigration and thus off-topic on our site

Comment: Oh, Sorry for that. So, could you suggest me where can I ask my question?

Comment: you can follow the [expatriates proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) . It needs some votes to get into beta phase

Comment: @Dirty-flow This question isn't about immigration, it's about a temporary visa.

Comment: @Dirty-flow and others [Meta discussion about medium-term travel](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/how-did-temporary-stays-longer-than-a-tourist-visa-become-off-topic)

Comment: Entry and re-entry is a topic of interest to most travellers. We're not talking about "permanent" arrangements. I voted to reopen.

Comment: I would've thought "request for residence" is pretty clearly in the realm of immigration/expats rather than travel. I'm not sure where we stand on questions which are about immigrants and expats travelling...

Comment: Now that the [Expatriates site has launched](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com), you might want to either re-ask the question there, or flag to have it migrated over (assuming you're still interested in the answer!)

Answer (score 6):

In short, **no**.   The [récépissé](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/F15763.xhtml) is a "receipt of request for residence", which is a temporary permit to stay in France while the bureaucrats scrutinize your paperwork, not a travel document or visa.  The scan you provide says you're permitted to *travailler* (work), but nothing about *voyager* (travel).

I would definitely get in touch with the French embassy in/nearest to your home country and see what they suggest: you will probably need to get your expired visa extended or re-issued.

**Updated** after realizing I had completely misread the original French doc. (Note to self: do not post on Travel.SE before first cup of coffee in the morning.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will contact the French embassy in my country. Actually, I have French visa, which is already expired, and OFII. I don't know if I can use the "Recepisse De Demande De Carte De Sejour" along with my OFII to re-enter to France. Would it give me more chance to re-enter?

Comment: +1 for answering, @jpatokal. It's nice to see people give useful answers despite question like these being closed (which I think is a terrible culture.) Good for you.

Comment: For people coming here from google, I, and many others, have got back into France many times on the récépissé with no problems. You need to carry the expired carte de sejour / ofii stamped passport with you.